# Refer to bibliography item of a different latex document

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm writing an appendix to a paper and it needs to be in a separate document. Is there a way to refer to a bibliography item of the paper, in the appendix? Obviously, `\cite{bla}` will not find the appropriate reference. However, I would prefer not to include another bibliography in the appendix with the same entries as the original paper but different numbering.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about creating one `.pdf` that you divide into two documents *ex post*?

Comment: I suppose I could do that, but it doesn't seem like an elegant solution. Then I would have to make sure I never forget to split the documents before I continue using them.